# Relating a variable number of rows in one table to one in another?

Tags: database-design

For an online store I'm currently considering the following SQL structure:

*Table 'productImages':*

```
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field          | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| productImageID | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| url            | varchar(200) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| baseWidth      | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| baseHeight     | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

*Table 'productImageSets':*

```
+-------------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field             | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| productImageSetID | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| productImageID1   | int(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| productImageID2   | int(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| productImageID3   | int(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| productImageID4   | int(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| productImageID5   | int(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| productImageID6   | int(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| productImageID7   | int(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| productImageID8   | int(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

*Table 'products':*

```
+-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field             | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| productID         | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| title             | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| description       | text         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| uploaded          | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| productImageSetID | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

As ugly as it looks and feels to me, this is the best I have so far.
The lowdown of it is that each product has a number of images, however this number is not the same for every product. This led me to creating the *productImageSets* table with the *productImageID(1-8)* columns, which each either point to a row in the *productImages* table, or are null.

What I'd like to know is if there's something I'm missing, or some better way to do this. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The classic way to realize many to many relation is with intermediate table. 
Like
Products(ID) - ProductImages(ProductID, ImageID) - Images(ID)
What is the reason to make these "sets"?

Comment: Well I feel dumb now! Thanks very much that's a very clear answer!

Comment: An issue I have withthis is about how incredibly space-inefficient it feels it's going to be. In a less simplified system, my interpretation of this method is that I have products in one table, which each have at least 18 variants (3 sizes * 6 colours) which are in another table, then each product has up to 15 images, but each of these images can be linked to multiple variants, meaning that the variantImages table receives around 5 entries for each variant, so I'm inserting 1 row into products, 18 into variants, 15 into images, and then 270 (18*15) entries into variantImages, any suggestions?

Comment: (Apologies if that's a little long winded/confusing)

Comment: This is very valid solution, nothing wrong with it. In VariantImages you'll have only reference to images (an int) and some variant description - so this is info that's needed by the business model. The goal is to have a normalized structure that represent your needs. In a later stage if you have performance issues you can start de-normalize some data or make materialzed views, cache queries and so on as a part of optimization strategy.

Comment: Ah okay, that's good to know - it just feels like I should be able to do something to increase the efficiency as each product will have 18 entries all the same other than size/colour. However, if you say this is the best solution, that's what I'll do. Thanks very much!